# c++ Program stops mid loop with no errors

Tags: c++, loops, console-application, simulator, terminate

I'm working on a hospital simulation program where patients are sorted by severity level and placed in corresponding queues. Everything seems to work fine when I'm debugging it, but for some reason, it  stops after a random amount of loops. I don't get any errors--my program just quits mid loop. What could cause that to happen?

```
priority_queue<Hospital_Visit> queue1, queue2;
vector<int> nurse_time_vector, doctor_time_vector;
vector<Hospital_Visit> current_hospital_visit;

for (int i = 0; i < master_hospital_visit.size(); i++){ //make a copy of the master_hospital_visit to manipulate
    current_hospital_visit.push_back(master_hospital_visit[i]);
}



if (num_nurses>0)
    nurse->set_minute(0);
if (num_doctors>0)
    doctor->set_minute(0);

int treatment;

map<string, vector<Hospital_Visit>>::iterator it;

srand(time(NULL));

bool hour_changed = true;

do{

    if (hour_changed){ //update queues with new hour's patients added to end
        for (int i = 0; i < current_hospital_visit.size(); i++){
            if (current_hospital_visit[i].get_hour() > current_hour){
                break;
            }
            if (current_hospital_visit[i].get_hour() <= current_hour)
            {
                if (current_hospital_visit[i].get_severity() <= 10) // For nurses
                {
                    queue1.push(current_hospital_visit[i]);
                    current_hospital_visit.erase(current_hospital_visit.begin() + i);
                }
                else // for doctors
                {
                    queue2.push(current_hospital_visit[i]);
                    current_hospital_visit.erase(current_hospital_visit.begin() + i);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    hour_changed = false;


        if (nurse->get_minute() != nurse->get_max_time() && queue1.size() != 0 && queue1.top().get_hour() <= current_hour && num_nurses > 0)
        {
            treatment = (rand() % 11) + 1;

            queue1.top().set_treatment_time(treatment);

            queue1.top().set_day(current_hour / 24);

            queue1.top().set_hour(current_hour);

            nurse->set_minute(treatment);

            queue1.top().set_wait_time(current_hour - queue1.top().get_hour() + treatment);

            queue1.top().set_medic(false);


            queue1.top().set_severity(queue1.top().get_severity() - (current_hour - queue1.top().get_hour()));


            it = patients_map.find(queue1.top().get_name());
            if (it == patients_map.end())
            {
                vector<Hospital_Visit> patient_visits;

                patient_visits.push_back(queue1.top());

                patients_map.insert(make_pair(queue1.top().get_name(), patient_visits));
            }
            else
            {
                it->second.push_back(queue1.top());
            }
            queue1.pop();
        }
        else if (queue1.size() == 0 && num_nurses > 0) //was !=
        {
            nurse_time_vector.push_back(nurse->get_max_time() - nurse->get_medic_hour());
        }

        if (doctor->get_medic_hour() != doctor->get_max_time() && queue2.size() != 0 &&
            queue2.top().get_hour() <= current_hour && num_doctors > 0)
        {
            treatment = (rand() % 21) + 1;

            queue2.top().set_treatment_time(treatment);

            queue2.top().set_day(current_hour / 24);

            queue2.top().set_hour(current_hour);

            doctor->set_minute(treatment);

            queue2.top().set_wait_time(current_hour - queue2.top().get_hour() + treatment);

            queue2.top().set_medic(true);

            queue2.top().set_severity(queue2.top().get_severity() - (current_hour - queue2.top().get_hour()));

            it = patients_map.find(queue2.top().get_name());
            if (it == patients_map.end())
            {

                vector<Hospital_Visit> patient_visits;

                patient_visits.push_back(queue2.top());

                patients_map.insert(make_pair(queue2.top().get_name(), patient_visits));
            }
            else
            {

                it->second.push_back(queue2.top());
            }
            queue2.pop();
        }

        else if (doctor->get_minute() != doctor->get_max_time() && queue1.size() != 0 && queue2.size() == 0
            && queue1.top().get_hour() <= current_hour && num_doctors > 0){

            treatment = (rand() % 21) + 1;

            queue1.top().set_treatment_time(treatment);

            queue1.top().set_day(current_hour / 24);

            queue1.top().set_hour(current_hour);

            doctor->set_minute(treatment);

            queue1.top().set_wait_time(current_hour - queue1.top().get_hour() + treatment);

            queue1.top().set_medic(true);

            queue1.top().set_severity(queue1.top().get_severity() - (current_hour - queue1.top().get_hour()));

            it = patients_map.find(queue1.top().get_name());
            if (it == patients_map.end())
            {
                vector<Hospital_Visit> patient_visits;
                patient_visits.push_back(queue1.top());
                patients_map.insert(make_pair(queue1.top().get_name(), patient_visits));
            }
            else
            {
                it->second.push_back(queue1.top());
            }
            queue1.pop();

        }

        if ((doctor->get_minute() <= doctor->get_max_time() + 20 && doctor->get_minute() >= doctor->get_max_time()-5) 
            || (queue1.size() == 0 && queue2.size() == 0))
            { // if the max time is reached or the queues are empty, then change the hour

            current_hour++;
            hour_changed = true;

            if (num_nurses>0)
                nurse->set_minute(0);
            if (num_doctors>0)
                doctor->set_minute(0);

            }

} while (current_hour != 169);
```

Comment: This is the perfect situation for learning how to use a debugger.

Comment: i've been debugging it for the last 3 hours. it doesn't give me any errors, and it doesn't even say the program exited. it just quits--i.e. the debugger stops.

Comment: If you want reproducibility, seed your PRNG with a constant value, or don't seed at all. Then run in the debugger. If a plain run doesn't show you where the error is, trace the execution step by step, to locate the offending line. Your question as it stands is unanswerable: too much code to spot the error by eyeballing, but not enough to reproduce it.

Comment: Where exectly does it stop? Which line? Is it always the same line?

Comment: I'd start by adding some exception handling.

Comment: If you have an infinite loop or wait, make the program enter that state, then *break* the execution from the debugger and look at the call stack.

Comment: "The debugger stops". This is an unusual behaviour for a debugger. Which debugger are you using, and how do you determine it's stopped?

Comment: it stops at a random place every time. could it be using too much memory and stopping because of that? it works when there are 3 or less patients coming in per hour, but any more than that seems to be too many

Comment: i'm using the visual studio local debugger. i set a breakpoint in my loop and pressed "continue." it should've outputted text at the end, but it dims out the "continue" button before the loop finishes.

Comment: Could you provide the rest of the source code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < current_hospital_visit.size(); i++){
    ...
    if (...)
    {
        current_hospital_visit.erase(current_hospital_visit.begin() + i);
    }
    ...
}
```

it will not check every element. Suppose `i` is `3`, and the `if` condition is true. Element `3` is erased, making element `4` the new element `3`. But in the next iteration, `i` is incremented and becomes `4`, so this new element `3` will never be tested.

A possible solution is to decrement `i` when you erase something:

```
for (int i = 0; i < current_hospital_visit.size(); i++){
    ...
    if (...)
    {
        current_hospital_visit.erase(current_hospital_visit.begin() + i);
        i--;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: My intent was to make a vector of hospital visits, then search through that vector for the items equal or below the "current hour," then add them to a treatment queue and delete them from the vector so that there aren't duplicates the next time it increments the hour. Does that logic make sense or should I try something different?

Comment: Yes, it makes sense, it's just that not all items equal or blow the current hour will be moved with the current code. You could for example write `i--` every time you move an element.

Comment: Oh I understand what you mean now. I'll give that a try!